# Setting CSS background dynamically in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, stylesheet

i have a Cordova Win8 Phone app, and in it.. i would like to set the background image attritube for the stylehseet dynamically.

```
#profile {
  background-image: url('**____SET__DYNAMICALLY____**');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top center;
  position: relative;
}
```

I tried below, but that doesnt work.

```
      document.getElementById("#profile")="background-image: url('" + bgimage + "');";
```

Any ideas on what could be up? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("profile").style.backgroundImage
    = "url(" + bgimage + ")";
```